# Why isn't my failed xpath expression causing an exception to be thrown in Selenium 2?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have the situation where I want the following code to throw an exception, but instead the web driver continually looks for the xpath expression without timing out:

```
    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='does-not-exist']"));
```

How do I get this to fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what version of Firefox you're using, so I'm going to use my psychic debugging powers to deduce you're attempting this with Firefox 17. There is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4814) with Firefox 17 and WebDriver 2.26. It will be fixed in 2.27, which will be released soon (note carefully how I am not committing to a date, because it's impossible to know for certain).

Comment: Correct. FF17 is the version. I didn't add the version because I assumed it wouldn't have mattered. Silly me.