# Selenium WebDriver findelement stuck java?

Tags: java, selenium, exception, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am writing  a very simple test case using selenium webdriver. Lets say I have

```
@Test
public void github_search() {
    this.webDriver.get("http://www.github.com");

    WebElement findBox = this.webDriver.findElement(By.id("qa"));

......
}
```

in this test, there is no element on the page with id of "qa", in this case I am excepting the findElement method to throw an exception. But it doesn't. Selenium actually appears to be stuck. Only thing I could do is manually close the browser.  I was wondering how to handle such situation where if the element doesn't exist then it waits for some time and, finally it should just throw an exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't my failed xpath expression causing an exception to be thrown in Selenium 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647532/why-isnt-my-failed-xpath-expression-causing-an-exception-to-be-thrown-in-seleni)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download latest 2.27 release:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Comment: 2.28 is available now. Please make sure that, you are using FF 12 or greater

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch Block and use implicit wait.

Comment: Thanks Barath, turns out its a bug with FF17 and Selenium, i downgraded my FF to 16 and it is working as intended.