# Selenium - Python find_element() waits for all ajax to load

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I am trying to log in on a website that has a lot of ajax. I have a slow connection so it takes some time, but I can see the login form and log in before all of the content loads. The login form is not loaded with ajax.

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get("http://www.example.com")
 print 'returned'

 print 'finding element'
 password_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'password')

 print 'sending password'
 password_element.send_keys('pass')
```

The output is:

```
>>returned
>>finding element
(waiting for 5 minutes)
>>sending password
```

It returns pretty fast and 'returned' is printed out. However it gets stuck in 'finding element' and it has to load all ajax before returning the element. In my firefox window WebDriver is written in the bottom bar in red, then it changes to black colour when everything is loaded.

My selenium version is 2.37.2 and firefox version 25.0.1. I saw on earlier posts that I should change the version but these are not applicable for these.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what your question is about. You've explained the situation, are you wanting it to be quicker? Not wait for all of the AJAX before continuing or something else?

Comment: @Mark Rowlands Exactly, I don't want to wait for all ajax to load on the main page, I want to log in directly.

Comment: Ok, the first thing I would try is to use `WebdriverWait` to explicitly wait for the `password_element`. So something like  `wait = WebdriverWait(driver, 10)    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("pass")`    I'm not 100% sure if using the explicit wait will 'break' the page-load timing but its worth at shot I guess.

Comment: I tried that, then the program first waits for 10 seconds, then get stuck at wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located - function. Actually it returns a web element if found. It seems others have the same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711799/selenium-webdriver-findelement-stuck-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919503/selenium-webdriver-stuck-when-find-element-method-called-with-a-non-existed-widg but with older versions. The annoying thing is that the form is always present in the browser so I can log in anytime.

Comment: Definitely seems to be an issue then. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to switch to the 'Chrome' (not Chromium) webdriver, it does not seem to have the same problem.